# Python logging - two loggers, two log files - how to configure logging.ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

It can be practical to have two or more distinct log files. For example for a Rest service, have  one log file for general failures and another for faults in the content.

I tried doing this using INI-file but for some reason all the logs would go to both files. So...

How would the *logging.ini* look like if I want all logs from logger1 to go to *logger1.log* and all logs from logger2 to go to *logger2.log*:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')
logger1 = logging.getLogger('name1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('name2')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

*python_logging.py*

```
import logging
from logging import config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')
logger1 = logging.getLogger('name1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('name2')

logger1.debug('This is logger1')
logger2.info('This is logger2')
logger1.warning('This is logger1')
logger1.error('This is logger1')
logger2.warning('This is logger2')
logger2.error('This is logger2')
```

*logging.ini*:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,name1,name2

[handlers]
keys=console_handler,file_handler_name1,file_handler_name2

[formatters]
keys=console_formatter,file_formatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=

[logger_name1]
level=INFO
handlers=console_handler,file_handler_name1
qualname=name1

[logger_name2]
level=INFO
handlers=console_handler,file_handler_name2
qualname=name2

[handler_console_handler]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=console_formatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file_handler_name1]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
formatter=file_formatter
args=('name1.log','a',1000000,100)

[handler_file_handler_name2]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
formatter=file_formatter
args=('name2.log','a',1000000,100)

[formatter_console_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s | %(name)s | %(message)s'
datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S

[formatter_file_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s | %(name)s | %(message)s'
datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
```